# Get table of map keys of JSON shape map visual in Power BI

Tags: json, powerbi, m

Is there any easy way to get table of the Map Keys of a map shape visual? I would like to get the map keys as a table of Power Query. The best would be to extract it from JSON file from which the map as been imported.

Download file: [NZ.json](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1vEIUxq66skdVpDlqojpAxmTBRqB0iKP4&export=download)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what your workflow is here but the query editor can read JSON files.

Comment: Hi Alexis, I updated my question. I share json file. I was not able to extract the values of map keys from it, though I found they are nested somewhere in the Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drill down on objects and geometries in the query editor, convert to a table, and expand the `properties` column:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\aolson\Downloads\NZ.json")),
    objects = Source[objects],
    gadm36_NZL_1 = objects[gadm36_NZL_1],
    geometries = gadm36_NZL_1[geometries],
    ConvertToTable = Table.FromList(geometries, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    ExpandColumn = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(ConvertToTable, "Column1", {"properties"}, {"properties"}),
    ExpandProperties = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(ExpandColumn, "properties", {"GID_0", "NAME_0", "GID_1", "NAME_1", "VARNAME_1", "NL_NAME_1", "TYPE_1", "ENGTYPE_1", "CC_1", "HASC_1"}, {"GID_0", "NAME_0", "GID_1", "NAME_1", "VARNAME_1", "NL_NAME_1", "TYPE_1", "ENGTYPE_1", "CC_1", "HASC_1"})
in
    ExpandProperties
```

---

If you want it a bit more dynamic, replace the single `ExpandProperties` formula line with these two:

```
ColumnNames = Record.FieldNames(ExpandColumn[properties]{0}),
ExpandProperties = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(ExpandColumn, "properties", ColumnNames, ColumnNames)
```

Comment: Well done:-) I was close. I was missing the step `Table.FromList`. I wanted to convert those nasty records to a table but could not click it out. Is it possible to mouse it from menu?

Comment: Yes. `To Table` is a button on the (List Tools) Transform tab.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding accepted answer of Alexis, I would like to go even more dynamic. The path to the file is the only variable.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\NZ.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    Value1 = #"Converted to Table"{3}[Value],
    #"Converted to Table1" = Record.ToTable(Value1),
    Value2 = #"Converted to Table1"{0}[Value],
    geometries = Value2[geometries],
    #"Converted to Table2" = Table.FromList(geometries, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table2", "Column1", {"arcs", "type", "properties"}, {"arcs", "type", "properties"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Column1",{"properties"}),
    ColumnNames = Record.FieldNames(#"Removed Other Columns"[properties]{0}),
    ExpandProperties = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "properties", ColumnNames, ColumnNames)
in 
    ExpandProperties
```