# Power BI shape map is lagging/not working

Tags: powerbi

I want to build a shape map in Power BI using postal area for Australia. I downloaded the [Correspondence, 2011 Postal Area to 2016 Postal Area](https://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1270.0.55.003July%202016?OpenDocument) and converted it to json file type on [mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/).

My data has a postcode column that looks like this:

[image]

and the map keys looks to be of the same format:

[image]

However, when I tried to plot the shape map by `sales` column (the value column), output looks like this

[image]

which doesn't zoom in. Is it because the data is too large? But there are only 300 rows in the table. How can I map out the areas by postcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No wonder your map loads slowly. You should simplify the map using [Mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/). Start with that. There could be another cause of the slowness in your measure you put on the map color saturation. Start with the simplest possible measure such as SUM( Table[no of kangaroos] ), avoid SUMX or IF in that measure. You could use Daxstudio to check the performance of the measure.

[image]

Comment: Hi Przemyslaw, thanks for sharing the very helpful tip, but I noticed that simplifying the file would accidentally remove the postcode, resulting in postcode undefined in Power BI, is there a way we can simplify the map while keeping the postcode?

Comment: This should be helpful in dynamically getting the map keys: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58593782/1903793 I do not think that in share map files would be postal codes. You should keep them in an additional dictionary which matches them with map keys.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "in share map files would be postal codes"? The map keys actually show that POA_CODE and POA_NAME are postcode, isn't it?

Comment: That is probably an additional dried-up salad in your sandwich. In the raw TopoJSON file, you got only the necessities to create a map. https://github.com/topojson/topojson-specification Your zip codes is a residue of some dbf file. Put that dbf file also in Mapshaper. I do it in my movie - I drag-drop there four files. I am not sure if Gadm files have that zip codes. Alternatively, build your model by establishing relationships between keys of TopoJSON file and some other table, a dictionary, which matches the keys of TopoJSON with zip codes.

Comment: Check this out: https://handsondataviz.org/mapshaper.html#join-spreadsheet-data-with-polygon-map It is about joining other information from csv file.

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer or at least up-voting it, if it helped.

Comment: Hi, I have accepted the answer. Cheers